# How to use the dropna() to drop itme which is < 1?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame as follow:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'Name1':(4.2, 0.3), 'Name2':(0.2, 4.2), 'Name3':(3.3, 5.5)}, index=('Val1', 'Val2'))
```

How can I drop a column in which any item's value < 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using [dropna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) is:

```
df
Out[34]: 
      Name1  Name2  Name3
Val1    4.2    0.2    3.3
Val2    0.3    4.2    5.5

In [35]: df[df<1]=np.nan

In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
      Name1  Name2  Name3
Val1    4.2    NaN    3.3
Val2    NaN    4.2    5.5

In [37]: df.dropna(axis=1,how='any',inplace=True)

In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
      Name3
Val1    3.3
Val2    5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This selects columns where all elements are `>=1` (complement of any of them being smaller than 1):

```
mydf.ix[:, ~(mydf<1).any()]
Out[9]: 
      Name3
Val1    3.3
Val2    5.5
```